# How do I detect "shift+enter" and generate a new line in Textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Currently, if the person presses <kbd>enter</kbd> inside the text area, the form will submit.
Good, I want that.

But when they type <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd>, I want the textarea to move to the next line: `\n`

How can I do that in `JQuery` or plain JavaScript as simple as possible?

Comment: Can you show us your current code?

Comment: I'm building a chat room. That's how Skype doe sit.

Comment: Check for `e.shiftKey`.

Comment: All you need to do is find the code that prevents Enter from submitting the form and check for the event's `shiftKey` property.

Comment: Here's a screenshot of console.log(event) http://filegr.am/buckets/f/jNk4D1DY/0

Comment: Shift ENTER for a new line in a text field isn't "changed" behaviour. It has been expected behaviour for donkey's years, for all sorts of things. I used it decades ago when entering text in spreadsheets.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

## Better use simpler solution:

Tim's solution below is better I suggest using that:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6015906/4031815

---

## My solution

I think you can do something like this..

**EDIT :** Changed the code to work irrespective of the caret postion

First part of the code is to get the caret position.

Ref: [How to get the caret column (not pixels) position in a textarea, in characters, from the start?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263743/how-to-get-cursor-position-in-textarea)

```
function getCaret(el) { 
    if (el.selectionStart) { 
        return el.selectionStart; 
    } else if (document.selection) { 
        el.focus();
        var r = document.selection.createRange(); 
        if (r == null) { 
            return 0;
        }
        var re = el.createTextRange(), rc = re.duplicate();
        re.moveToBookmark(r.getBookmark());
        rc.setEndPoint('EndToStart', re);
        return rc.text.length;
    }  
    return 0; 
}
```

And then replacing the textarea value accordingly when <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> together , submit the form if <kbd>Enter</kbd> is pressed alone.

```
$('textarea').keyup(function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        var content = this.value;  
        var caret = getCaret(this);          
        if(event.shiftKey){
            this.value = content.substring(0, caret - 1) + "\n" + content.substring(caret, content.length);
            event.stopPropagation();
        } else {
            this.value = content.substring(0, caret - 1) + content.substring(caret, content.length);
            $('form').submit();
        }
    }
});
```

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jishnuap/zYEMv/)

Comment: That won't work if the caret is not at the end of the textarea's content.

Comment: Also, there's a typo (you mean `event.keyCode == 13`) and I think you probably also wanted `event.preventDefault()` rather than `event.stopPropagation()`.

Comment: I changed it. Now it'll work irrespective of caret position. And by `event.stopPropagation()` i meant to stop some other code which he may have written to submit the form.

Comment: That caret position function is flawed (see my comment and answer on the linked caret position question), and you don't need the caret position to do this anyway. See my answer here. Re `event.stopPropagation()`, that will prevent the event from bubbling further up the DOM but will not prevent the keypress from doing its default action of inserting a line break (although actually in `keyup` my suggestion of `event.preventDefault()` won't do that either).

Comment: Although it worked fine, but it gave error that `carent` is not defined, if i change it to caret it adds 2 new lines

Comment: `getCaret` function can be replaced by this library - https://github.com/timdown/rangy

Comment: @JishnuAP also gets an error that `carent is not defined`

Answer (score 210):

## Easy & Elegant solution:

First, pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> inside a textarea does not submit the form unless you have script to make it do that. That's the behaviour the user expects and I'd recommend against changing it. However, if you must do this, the easiest approach would be to find the script that is making <kbd>Enter</kbd> submit the form and change it. The code will have something like

```
if (evt.keyCode == 13) {
    form.submit();
}
```

... and you could just change it to

```
if (evt.keyCode == 13 && !evt.shiftKey) {
    form.submit();
}
```

---

On the other hand, if you don't have access to this code for some reason, you need to do the following to make it work in all major browsers even if the caret is not at the end of the text:

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zd3gA/1/

Code:

```
function pasteIntoInput(el, text) {
    el.focus();
    if (typeof el.selectionStart == "number"
            && typeof el.selectionEnd == "number") {
        var val = el.value;
        var selStart = el.selectionStart;
        el.value = val.slice(0, selStart) + text + val.slice(el.selectionEnd);
        el.selectionEnd = el.selectionStart = selStart + text.length;
    } else if (typeof document.selection != "undefined") {
        var textRange = document.selection.createRange();
        textRange.text = text;
        textRange.collapse(false);
        textRange.select();
    }
}

function handleEnter(evt) {
    if (evt.keyCode == 13 && evt.shiftKey) {
        if (evt.type == "keypress") {
            pasteIntoInput(this, "\n");
        }
        evt.preventDefault();
    }
}

// Handle both keydown and keypress for Opera, which only allows default
// key action to be suppressed in keypress
$("#your_textarea_id").keydown(handleEnter).keypress(handleEnter);
```

Comment: How do I distinguish left shift and right shift? Say, enter+left shift send message, enter+right shift clear message. I checked `event.location == KeyboardEvent.DOM_KEY_LOCATION_LEFT`, it doesn't work because when the key down, the key is Enter, not the shift, so it's always DOM_KEY_LOCATION_STANDARD.

Answer (score 53):

Most of these answers overcomplicate this.  Why not try it this way?

```
$("textarea").keypress(function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13 && !event.shiftKey) {
         submitForm(); //Submit your form here
         return false;
         }
});
```

No messing around with caret position or shoving line breaks into JS.  Basically, the function will not run if the shift key is being pressed, therefore allowing the enter/return key to perform its normal function.

Answer (score 21):

Why not just

```
$(".commentArea").keypress(function(e) {
    var textVal = $(this).val();
    if(e.which == 13 && e.shiftKey) {

    }
    else if (e.which == 13) {
       e.preventDefault(); //Stops enter from creating a new line
       this.form.submit(); //or ajax submit
    }
});
```

Comment: You can just use one condition like (event.keyCode == 13 && !event.shiftKey). Just a tip: if you use knockoutjs, you need to unfocus the textarea fist to update the value: jQuery(this).blur();

Comment: you are the man for "stops enter from creating a new line" :)

Answer (score 4):

Use the [jQuery hotkeys](http://code.google.com/p/js-hotkeys/) plugin and this code

```
jQuery(document).bind('keydown', 'shift+enter', 
         function (evt){ 
             $('textarea').val($('#textarea').val() + "\n");// use the right id here
             return true;
         }
);
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is an AngularJS solution using [ng-keyup](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngKeyup) if anyone has the same issue using AngularJS.

```
ng-keyup="$event.keyCode == 13 && !$event.shiftKey && myFunc()"
```

Answer (score 4):

Using ReactJS ES6 here's the simplest way

<kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd> New Line at any position

<kbd>enter</kbd> Blocked

```js
class App extends React.Component {

 constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      message: 'Enter is blocked'
    }
  }
  onKeyPress = (e) => {
     if (e.keyCode === 13 && e.shiftKey) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let start = e.target.selectionStart,
            end = e.target.selectionEnd;
        this.setState(prevState => ({ message:
            prevState.message.substring(0, start)
            + '\n' +
            prevState.message.substring(end)
        }),()=>{
            this.input.selectionStart = this.input.selectionEnd = start + 1;
        })
    }else if (e.keyCode === 13) { // block enter
      e.preventDefault();
    }
    
  };

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
      New line with shift enter at any position<br />
       <textarea 
       value={this.state.message}
       ref={(input)=> this.input = input}
       onChange={(e)=>this.setState({ message: e.target.value })}
       onKeyDown={this.onKeyPress}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='root'></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

And jquery example

```js
$.fn.pressEnter = function(fn) {
    return this.each(function() {  
        $(this).bind('enterPress', fn);
        $(this).keyup(function(e){
        
            /*When SHIFT return false*/
            if(e.shiftKey==true) return false;

            if(e.keyCode == 13)
            {
              /*You can do the thing on ENTER*/
              alert('Enter press');
            }

        })
    });  
}; 
$('.exampleClass').pressEnter(function(){})
```

```css
div{
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  border:solid 1px #000;
  float:left;
}
textarea{
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  border:solid 1px #000;
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="exampleClass" contenteditable></div>

<textarea  class="exampleClass"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 2):

I found this thread looking for a way to control Shift + any key.  I pasted together other solutions to make this combined function to accomplish what I needed.  I hope it helps someone else.

```
function () {
    return this.each(function () {
    $(this).keydown(function (e) {
        var key = e.charCode || e.keyCode || 0;
        // Shift + anything is not desired
        if (e.shiftKey) {
            return false;
        }
        // allow backspace, tab, delete, enter, arrows, numbers 
        //and keypad numbers ONLY
        // home, end, period, and numpad decimal
        return (
            key == 8 ||
            key == 9 ||
            key == 13 ||
            key == 46 ||
            key == 110 ||
            key == 190 ||
            (key >= 35 && key <= 40) ||
            (key >= 48 && key <= 57) ||
            (key >= 96 && key <= 105));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I use div by adding contenteditable true instead of using textarea.

Hope can help you.

```
$("#your_textarea").on('keydown', function(e){//textarea keydown events
  if(e.key == "Enter")
  {
    if(e.shiftKey)//jump new line
    {
     // do nothing
    }
    else  // do sth,like send message or else
    {
       e.preventDefault();//cancell the deafult events
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

**Another Solution for detecting Shift+Enter Key with Angular2+**

Inside Component.html

`<input type="text" (keydown.shift.enter)="newLine($event)">`

Inside Component.ts

```
newLine(event){
      if(event.keyCode==13 && event.shiftKey){
        alert('Shift+Enter key Pressed');
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

**This code works perfectly fine for my purpose**

```js
document.getElementById('text').addEventListener('keypress', (e) => {
  if (e.key == 'Enter' && !e.shiftKey) {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log('your code goes here');
  }
  if (e.key == 'Enter' && e.shiftKey) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("insertLineBreak");
    const txtArea = document.getElementById('text');
    txtArea.value += '\r\n';
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me!

```
$("#your_textarea").on('keydown', function(e){
    if(e.keyCode === 13 && !e.shiftKey) 
    {

          $('form').submit();

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

using `ng-keyup` directive in angularJS, only send a message on pressing `Enter` key and `Shift+Enter` will just take a new line.

```
ng-keyup="($event.keyCode == 13&&!$event.shiftKey) ? sendMessage() : null"
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is still wondering how to do this without jQuery.

HTML

`<textarea id="description"></textarea>`

Javascript

```
const textarea = document.getElementById('description');

textarea.addEventListener('keypress', (e) => {
    e.keyCode === 13 && !e.shiftKey && e.preventDefault(); 
})
```

Vanilla JS

```
var textarea = document.getElementById('description');

textarea.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode === 13 && !e.shiftKey) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I wanted to toss in an implicit observation that some might want to consider if using `Shift` + `A-Z`.

```
document.onkeydown = (k) => {
  if (k.key === "Q") {
    console.log("Shift + Q");
  }
}
```

You can check for a key by its case, like `"Q"` or `"q"`. If doing the former, then it's implied that `Shift` is being pressed since it's a capital letter.

One bug here where functionality is concerned is if `CapsLock` is on. But if, like me, you're utilizing it in a personal script, then it's not really a big deal.

Another potential benefit might be "hiding" an explicit condition looking for the `Shift` key to be pressed. This is admittedly a half-baked suggestion, though.

Answer (score 0):

Some complicated solutions sending `\n` are not necessary.
On `keydown` event just return the key `13` if shift is pressed

```js
​$("#mytestarea").keydown(function (e) {
   ​
   ​if (e.keyCode == 13) { // Enter pressed
       //No shift or alt or ctrl
       ​if (!e.shiftKey && !e.altKey && !e.ctrlKey) {
           ​SendMsg(); // or submit or what you wan't
       ​}
       ​if (e.shiftKey) {
           //replace the shift for keycode 13 only
           ​return 13;
       ​}
                   ​
       ​//method to prevent from default behaviour
       ​e.preventDefault();
   ​}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" onkeydown="handleMessageKeydown" />
```

or some content editable element:

```
<div contenteditable="true" onchange="handleMessageKeydown" />

handleMessageKeydown(e) {
      if (!e.shiftKey && e.key === "Enter") {
          e.preventDefault()
          sendMessage()
      }
 }
```

if shift is pressed with enter then it will create new lines otherwise it will fall inside the if condition given above. Inside the if condition, the e.preventDefault() line is the most important. For a keydown event handler, the e.preventDefault() stops running the operation so that u can perform your own operations like sending messages to server etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the best way to do

```
  if (e.key === 'Enter') {
    console.log('enter');
  }
  if (e.key === 'Enter' && e.ctrlKey) {
    console.log('clt+enter');
  }
  if (e.key === 'Enter' && e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey) {
    console.log('clt+shift+enter');
  }
```