# Submit value on pressing Enter in textarea and pressing Shift+Enter should go to next line

Tags: javascript, jquery, keypress

I want to have a chat box (textarea) where if user press Enter then it should submit the chat, and if user press Shift+Enter then it should enter in a new line.

I tried something but not able to figure out the exact keyup or keydown thing. The code I'm using at the moment is:

```
$("textarea").keydown(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 13 && !e.shiftKey)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Su5ts/)

Also I want to get the `\n` in place when Enter+Shift key is pressed.

**EDIT**

Issue with my code is:-

When i am check the content on client using using alert then it shows the next line. But when i am posting it my rails back end. Then its just a simple string. No new line thing is there.

This is how i am sending chats to rails server.

```
  $.post("/incomingchat", { body:$("#chat_" + group_id).val() },
   function(data){
        // do something..
    });
```

Comment: Please don't **just** link to jsfiddle; always include the code in the question as well.

Comment: What's wrong with the code you posted? To me it works just as you described? http://jsfiddle.net/Su5ts/25/

Comment: @Matt Sorry, will keep this thing in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've answered this before. It's a little tricky if the caret is not at the end of the textarea:

[How do I detect "shift+enter" and generate a new line in Textarea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6014702/how-do-i-detect-shiftenter-and-generate-a-new-line-in-textarea/6015906#6015906)

Comment: The issue is when i m posting this data using Jquery to my backend server. How can i identity the enter+shift key? at back end its same as without enter+shift key

Comment: @Mohit: I don't understand. The value of the textarea after pressing shift+enter will contain a line break and this line break will definitely be submitted to the server when you post.

Comment: @TimDown: I have a related question. In Chrome, if I handle keypress event when enter key is pressed by adding new line character '\n', and if the textarea is scrollable, the scrollbar won't work, I mean if I press enter key, textarea doesn't scroll when I type. Do you have any idea for this problem?

Answer (score 3):

```
$("textarea").keydown(function(e)
{
    if (e.keyCode == 13)
    {
        if (e.shiftKey) {
            $(this).val( $(this).val() + "\n" );
        }
        else {
            submitTheChat();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: The issue is when i m posting this data using Jquery to my backend server. How can i identity the enter+shift key? at back end its same as without enter+shift key

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the keypress event instead. If you run the code in jsfiddle, you'll see that a new line is not added when you press enter.

```
$("textarea").keypress(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 13 && !e.shiftKey)
    {        
        e.preventDefault();
        //now call the code to submit your form
        alert("just enter was pressed");
        return;
    }

    if (e.keyCode == 13 && e.shiftKey)
    {       
        //this is the shift+enter right now it does go to a new line
        alert("shift+enter was pressed");        
    }    
});
```

Comment: The issue is when i m posting this data using Jquery to my backend server. How can i identity the enter+shift key? at back end its same as without enter+shift key

Comment: Ok I see. In that case I suggest looking at Tim Down's response that he has posted above.