# How to submit the form by using Enter key when the focus is in multi line textbox?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax, c#-4.0

I am using a multi line textbox and button .I just want to submit the form when user press enter key so I set the defaultbutton for the form is button id and I just want to set focus to multi line textbox after page load but when I press the enter key  it is going to the new line, form is not submitting.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" defaultbutton="btnSend" >
<table>
<tr><td>Message: </td><td><asp:TextBox ID="txtMsg" CssClass="mymsg" TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
        <td colspan="2"><asp:Button ID="btnSend" runat="server" onclick="btnSend_Click" 
                OnClientClick="scroll()" Text="send" />
        </td></tr>        
        </table>
```

Can anyone please help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Did you tried anything to solve your problem? Show your effort first. You can read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: wouldn't that defeat the purpose of multi line textbox ?

Answer (score 0):

You can set default button property in  tag

Answer (score 0):

Alternate solution:
Submit the form on <kbd>enter</kbd>
and for next line <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd>

try this [`DEMO`](http://jsfiddle.net/jishnuap/zYEMv/)

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6014702/how-do-i-detect-shiftenter-and-generate-a-new-line-in-textarea)