# Textarea Shift+Enter for next line and Enter to submit the form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

In textarea when the user presses **Shift+Enter** then it should continue in next new line and when he simply presses **Enter** it should submit the form without using submit button.

Here is the **[Fiddle!!](http://jsfiddle.net/fastnto/eUaLt/)**

I have browsed a lot but doesn't helped me, detailed explanation appreciated
Please help me!!

**Code**

```
$('commenttextarea').keyup(function (event) {
   if (  event.shiftKey && event.keyCode == 13) {
       var content = this.value;
       var caret = getCaret(this);
       this.value = content.substring(0,caret)+"\n"+content.substring(carent,content.length-1);
       event.stopPropagation();

  }else if(event.keyCode == 13)
  {
      $('commentform').submit();
  }});
```

Comment: Possible dublicate [of this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6014702/how-do-i-detect-shiftenter-and-generate-a-new-line-in-textarea)

Comment: @Oli yeah exactly, but that doesn't solved my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**First,** You missed to load any **jquery version**

**Second,** you missed `#` before `textarea` and `form selectors`.

Also use `caret` not `carent` in line

```
this.value = content.substring(0,caret)+"\n"+content.substring(caret,content.length-1);
                          // ----------------------------------^
```

**Full Code**

```
function getCaret(el) {
    if (el.selectionStart) {
        return el.selectionStart;
    } else if (document.selection) {
        el.focus();
        var r = document.selection.createRange();
        if (r == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        var re = el.createTextRange(),
            rc = re.duplicate();
        re.moveToBookmark(r.getBookmark());
        rc.setEndPoint('EndToStart', re);
        return rc.text.length;
    }
    return 0;
}
$('#commenttextarea').keyup(function (event) {
    if (event.shiftKey && event.keyCode == 13) {
        var content = this.value;
        var caret = getCaret(this);
        this.value = content.substring(0, caret) + "\n" + content.substring(caret, content.length - 1);
        event.stopPropagation();
    } else if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        $('#commentform').submit();
    }
});
```

See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/eUaLt/1/) would work

Comment: Rohan kumar! Does fiddle require jquery version??
and i il try with your second suggestion.

Comment: Yes, **Fiddle** doesn't add any `library` or `framework` by itself.

Comment: @Fastnto if you want to use jQuery within a jsFiddle, then you need to select a Version of jQuery on the left side of jsFiddle in the drop-down saying `No-Library (pure JS)`.

Comment: @RohanKumar **Shift+Enter** isn't working with **[This](http://jsfiddle.net/eUaLt/1/)**

Comment: @RohanKumar hey sorry, both the operations are working in fiddle. But **Enter** to submit the form is not working in FF, Safari and IE. Instead both the operations are working as **Shift+Enter**

Comment: @Fastnto If you provide `action` in `form tag` then it will `submit` like, `<form id="commentform" action="test.php">` see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/eUaLt/2/)

Answer (score 0):

As [Rohan Kumar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20742523/490560) said: you forgot the [id Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/):

```
$('#commenttextarea').keyup(function (event) {
   if (  event.shiftKey && event.keyCode == 13) {
       var content = this.value;
       var caret = getCaret(this);
       this.value = content.substring(0,caret)+"\n"+content.substring(carent,content.length-1);
       event.stopPropagation();

  }else if(event.keyCode == 13)
  {
      $('#commentform').submit();
  }});
```