# javascript focus search form on keydown ? (question mark)

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, search, input

How do I focus search form input field when these two keys are pressed using Javascript?

<kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> will generate the <kbd>?</kbd>

So basically, on keydown for question mark, the search form gets autofocus.

---

Here is my current bootstrap 3 search form code:

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="form" method="post" action="{$WEB_ROOT}/knowledgebase.php?action=search">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input id="inputMessage" class="form-control" placeholder="Search website.com" type="text" name="search">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"></button>
</form>
```

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6014702/how-do-i-detect-shiftenter-and-generate-a-new-line-in-textarea

Comment: @user7411567 , I made a small change. moved the `e.preventDefault();` to inside of `if` in the answer. Please update the code in your production site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this code.

Create an object to store the keypress and add an eventListener which add each key press to the Object.

Then check for the keyCodes <kbd>Shift</kbd>(16) and <kbd>/</kbd>(191)

```js
var map = {}; //to store the keycodes
onkeydown = onkeyup = function(e){
    e = e || event;
    
    map[e.keyCode] = e.type == 'keydown';
    
    if(map["16"]==true && map["191"]==true){  // 16 => shift and 191 /
      e.preventDefault();
      var elm=document.getElementById('inputMessage');
      elm.focus();
      
    }
    /* insert conditional here */
}
```

```html
<form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="form" method="post" action="{$WEB_ROOT}/knowledgebase.php?action=search">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input id="inputMessage" class="form-control" placeholder="Search website.com" type="text" name="search">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"></button>
</form>
```

Comment: Note: `keyCode` is deprecated:  [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode)

Comment: @buchstabe Thanks for the update. Deprecated code will still work for few more months/ years. According to MDN, the alternative is `code` and it's not implemented by all browsers. _you should use KeyboardEvent.code, if it's implemented. Unfortunately, some browsers still don't have it_. I've to check for browser support and will update the answer

Answer (score 2):

try

```
$(document).on('keypress',function(e){
   if(e.keyCode == 63 ) {
      $("#inputMessage").focus()
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This work. You have to use the event `e.shiftKey` with the keycode of the `/` button (I used 219 because it's the ? position in the italian keyboard layout)

```js
$(document).on('keydown', function(e){
  if(e.shiftKey && e.keyCode == 219)
  {
    $("#search").focus();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="search">
```

Answer (score 0):

This works, but maybe you advise more clean solution?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).keyup('keyup', function(event){
    if(event.which === 191) {
        $('#inputMessage').focus();
    }
});
</script>
```

Maybe it shouldn't be *keyup* or perhaps the *focus* is not best. Whatcha think? I'm looking for the absolute superior way to achieve results.

Comment: check my answer.