# Press a button to input text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a message system where you type a message such as "Hello" and it will POST it to the server and the user will be able to see it.

Is there a way where if a user presses shift+enter they can create a new paragraph?

**How a message looks currently:**

Hello John, How are you?

**How a message should look (By pressing shift+enter after the comma):**

Hello John,

How are you?

---

**PS**

***I am very sorry for not creating some sort of fiddle here, but I couldn't really think of what to put in it or how I could demonstrate it.***

**Thanks so much!**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6014702/how-do-i-detect-shiftenter-and-generate-a-new-line-in-textarea

Comment: Don't have much idea about it but you will need to create short cuts using jquery ...

Comment: @Just_Do_It That's what I was thinking, I would need to somehow bind shift+enter to make a new line or something... But I have no idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6014702/how-do-i-detect-shiftenter-and-generate-a-new-line-in-textarea) you could use this

```js
  
$('#paragraph').keyup(function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        var content = this.value;        
        if(event.shiftKey){
            this.value = content.substring(0, this.value.length) + "\n";
            event.stopPropagation();
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="paragraph" rows="4" cols="30"></textarea>
```

Comment: I still want enter to submit the form. (So SHIFT+Enter creates a new line and enter will submit the form) Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<textarea rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
```

JS

```
$("textarea").keydown(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 13 && !e.shiftKey)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

[TRY HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/2xsnLszh/)

Comment: I still want enter to submit the form. (So SHIFT+Enter creates a new line and enter will submit the form) Thank you.