# Submit Form Inside TextArea with Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, form-submit

I am trying to submit my form while in a textarea when they hit enter. If they hit Enter + Shift then I want to make a new line in the textarea.

I also want to prevent a postback when enter is hit and this is what I am having a problem with.

```
<form ref={el => this.myFormRef = el} onSubmit={this.searchClick} autoComplete="off">
       <textarea
                  ref={input => input && input.focus()}
                  className="textarea"
                  name="search-area"
                  rows={this.rowCount}
                  value={this.searchValue}
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                  onKeyDown={this.onKeyDown}
                />
</form>




 @action
  searchClick = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
  }

  @action
  onKeyDown = event => {
    if (event.key == 'Enter' && event.shiftKey == false) {
      this.myFormRef.submit();
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
    }

    this.searchValue = event.target.value;
  };
```

Comment: Find answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6014702/how-do-i-detect-shiftenter-and-generate-a-new-line-in-textarea

Comment: The react answer does not do use a form submit as far as I can see.

Comment: I haven't tried but i suppose you can do this.myFormRef.submit(); instead of form submit.